# embedded bootup splash-screen solution

Tags: embedded-linux, splash-screen, yocto

I have an embedded system built with YoctoProject's poky (1.6.1) environment. I have a main application and it's using Qt for user interaction with a 7" touchscreen.

Now it's a bit "ugly" when the user turns on the device he has to wait 1-2 minutes and see how linux is booting up. To avoid this I installed psplash on my embedded system, that helps a bit, it's fading away linux bootup, but when we get the login prompt it exits.

Now I need a solution where the splashscreen is going to stay alive until my application is not ready to "get" the screen.

Do I need to modify psplash's source? (or any other splashscreen application) or maybe there is a general technique for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to follow this [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg08038.html) . I followed them and I can change splash screen, although I've used core-image-sato. Which image are you using?

To follow this steps, you have to convert your image in .h file. To do this step, you must download [make-image-header.sh](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/psplash/tree) and do:

```
cp <your-image.jpg> your-image
./make-image-header.sh your-image POKY
```

Comment: "make-image-header.sh" requires the following package to be installed: "sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev"